# Tikzcd styles error

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-cd

I'm trying to get to grips with using styles in tikz but I'm struggling to work out what is wrong with the following example.

The problem is that both 'arrows' should appear simply as lines (like the second one does), however the first one still has the arrow head.
PDFLaTeX also finishes 'with exit code 1'.

Incidentally, I didn't realise this issue with this example, but with a more complicated example.
However, strangely my more complicated example did render as I expected, although still claimed to finish with exit code 1 (though I didn't try to use the `dash` style when defining the `my dash` style).

Many thanks in advanced.

[image: Diagram produced by code below]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\tikzset{my dash/.style=dash}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \arrow[d, my dash] & A \arrow[d, dash]\\
  B                    & B
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the style to the correct hierarchy, or, better yet, using `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzcdset{my dash/.style=dash}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \arrow[d, my dash] & A \arrow[d, dash]\\
  B                    & B
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternative way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\tikzset{commutative diagrams/my dash/.style=dash}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \arrow[d, my dash] & A \arrow[d, dash]\\
  B                    & B
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `dash` is an interesting name for the style compared to its function. Does it simply removes whatever default arrow head? `-` should do the same.

Comment: So it does, I got it from the Tikz-cd documentation (page 4)
https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf

I guess `dash` is just `-` written as a word!

Thanks to both of you!